# Using multiple instances of a WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, dns, cluster-computing

I am very very to WCF. Rather this is my first shot at WCF. I have a service that just works fine on my local system. I have the following requirement. I need to host the service in a clustered server environment. I will have a group of lets say 3 servers. How should I go about hosting the service? I want to host it in the IIS. Do I host the service on all three servers? If so how would they fall back in case the primary server is down for some reason. Can I have one single endpoint address pointing to the active server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write the code without using session state you can use a load balancer in front of the 3 servers to handle the clustering.  Be sure to write the code in a way that it does not matter what server you are on when the call is executed, since it could be different one call to the next.